# How to Mock Custom Jackson Deserializer Response in Spring Boot 1.5.9

Tags: java, spring-boot, mockito, spring-test-mvc, jackson-databind

In a Spring Boot 1.5.9 project, I'm currently trying to use `@WebMvcTest` to run a test against one of my controllers. The entity being operated on has a `@JsonDeserializer()` annotation on one of its properties pointing to a custom class. I'm attempting to mock the result of the `deserialize()` call in a test without invoking the body.

However, when trying to do the following, I'm getting a NullPointerException error on a line within the `deserialize()` method, which suggests the actual method body is being executed:

```
@Autowired
private MockMvc mvc;
@MockBean
private MyDeserializer myDeserializer
[...]
@Test
public void myTestMethod() {
  doReturn(myDeserializedValue)
      .when(myDeserializer)
      .deserialize(
          any(JsonParser.class),
          any(DeserializationContext.class)
      );
  this.mvc.perform([...]) // perform mvc call that would invoke myDeserializer
  logger.debug("Call complete"); // never gets to this line
}
```

I'm assuming the custom deserializer class is being invoked (possibly `new`ed up) outside of the knowledge of Spring's ApplicationContext.

Is there any way to mock a custom deserializer, or do I need to bump this class up to use the full ApplicationContext via `@SpringBootTest` and let it fully execute?

Answer (score 0):

If you want Jackson to use a specific deserializer object instance you need to register it via a module on the ObjectMapper instance. See [the docs](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-docs/wiki/JacksonHowToCustomSerializers#with-jackson-17-and-above) for an example with a serializer; you'll have to modify it slightly for your deserializer.

Otherwise, I assume Jackson will just instantiate a new instance of your class every time and never use your mock (or bean?) at all.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm still getting the same error when registering the deserializer in the setUp method and using that mapper. [This article](http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-deserialization) suggests that deserializers specified via `@JsonDeserialize()` don't have to be added, which makes me wonder if you can't override it so easily.

Comment: Maybe try removing the annotation on the class? Jackson should know from the registration what class your deserializer handles.